# Unable to display the intended Dialog box from xml file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, user-interface, android-alertdialog

[image of xml layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNS8e.png)
[image of output on emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJiLX.png)
I'm trying to write a code to display custom dialog box on clicking menu options using xml layout file. On running the app in Android studio I'm not getting the desired dialog box, i.e the EditText fields are not showing up,also the layout is different from what I set up in xml file, Please help

This is the code in onOptionsItemSelected block

```
//Add New Sample 
else if (id == R.id.new_sample) { 
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this); 
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.dialogtoaddsample,null); 
EditText sampleNameinput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.samplename_input); EditText genderinput = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.gender_input); 
Button submit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.submit_button); 
Button cancel = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);    

alert.setView(view);

    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
    alertDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    alertDialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialogtoaddsample);
    alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    alertDialog.show();

    cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { String samplenameEt = sampleNameinput.getText().toString().trim();
            String readpath = Contact.getFolderPath(MainActivity.this);
            String sameTemp = new String();
            File f = new File(readpath);
            if (f.exists()) {
                File file\[\] = f.listFiles();
                for (int i = 0; i \< file.length; i++) {
                    if (Objects.equals(file\[i\].getName(), samplenameEt)) {
                        sameTemp = samplenameEt;
                    }
                }
            }
            String currentDate = getDate();
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(samplenameEt)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The sample name cannot be empty!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else if (Objects.equals(sameTemp, samplenameEt)) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "The sample name cannot be same as others!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                //\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*\*
                File foldersample = new File(Contact.getFolderPath(MainActivity.this) + File.separator + samplenameEt);
                boolean success = true;
                if (!foldersample.exists()) {
                    success = foldersample.mkdirs();
                }
                if (success) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Blood sample " + samplenameEt +
                            " is added!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    db.addSamples(new SampleNameList());
                    showRecord();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Unable to create blood sample bank folder!"
                            , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        }

    });
```

I have attached both images of output of emulator and my xml layout

this is the xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_dialog"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="53dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="Add New Blood Sample"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="33dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
        android:text="Please enter the Name and Gender"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/gender_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="74dp"
        android:hint="Gender"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="start|top"

        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/samplename_input"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="124dp"
        android:hint="Name"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="Submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="28dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="14dp"
        android:text="Cancel" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="53dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Add New Blood Sample"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView13"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Please enter the Name and Gender"
    android:textColor="#000"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView1" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/samplename_input"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/gender_input"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Age"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/submit_button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/samplename_input" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/submit_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Submit"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/cancel_button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/submit_button" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```